# How to reset the allowClear opts in select2?

Tags: jquery-select2

In the following, I am able to update the select2 placeholder text by using opts and setPlaceholder. 
Is there any way I can also update the "allowClear" option? I could not find any select2 method that I can call to do this.
Any ideas?

```js
var data=[{id:0,tag:'foo'},{id:1,tag:'bar'}];

function format(item) { return item.tag };

function update() {
    //$('#choose').select2("destroy");
    $('#choose').data('select2').opts.placeholder='test';

    $('#choose').data('select2').setPlaceholder();
};


$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#choose').select2({
        width: '100px',
        allowClear: true,
        placeholder: 'yooyoo'});
    
    $("#button").click(function () {
        update();
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://select2.github.io/select2/select2-3.5.1/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://select2.github.io/select2/select2-3.5.1/select2.js"></script>
<select id="choose">
            <option></option><!-- Needed to show X image to clear the select -->
            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="3">Option 3</option>
            <option value="4">Option 4</option>
            <option value="5">Option 5</option>
        </select>
<button id="button">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

`allowClear` is a part of the select2 configuration which cannot be changed dynamically as mentioned [here](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/2830):

> It is not currently possible to do this (**change options**) dynamically. The general idea of what needs to be done is:
>
> 1. Instance is destroyed
> 2. Instance is re-initialized with the modified options

Although there are many approaches to do this, here's one that I feel is a robust version of changing the options dynamically:

1. Setting the options as an object beforehand (consisting defaults):

   ```
   var options = {
     width: '100px',
     allowClear: true,
     placeholder: 'yooyoo'
   };
   ```
2. Function to initialize the select2 which will be called multiple times i.e. on option change.

   ```
   function initSelect() {
      $('#choose').select2(options);
   }
   ```
3. For example, let's update the placeholder - simple change the option's key and call `initSelect`.

   ```
   function update() {
      options.placeholder = 'test';
      initSelect();
   };
   ```

In a similar fashion, the `allowClear` option can be modified as well. Here's a code snippet:

```js
var data=[{id:0,tag:'foo'},{id:1,tag:'bar'}];

function format(item) { return item.tag };

var options = {
  width: '100px',
  allowClear: true,
  placeholder: 'yooyoo'
};

function update() {
    options.placeholder = 'test';
    initSelect();
}

function toggleClear() {
 options.allowClear = !options.allowClear;
  initSelect();
}
function initSelect() {
    $('#choose').select2(options);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  initSelect();
    $("#button").click(function () {
        update();
    });
   $("#toggleClear").click(function () {
        toggleClear();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://select2.github.io/select2/select2-3.5.1/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://select2.github.io/select2/select2-3.5.1/select2.js"></script>
<select id="choose">
            <option></option><!-- Needed to show X image to clear the select -->
            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="3">Option 3</option>
            <option value="4">Option 4</option>
            <option value="5">Option 5</option>
        </select>
<button id="button">Click</button>

<button id="toggleClear">Toggle Clear Option</button>
```

Also there is no specific method to reset the `allowClear` as you have for the placeholder (`setPlaceHolder`). Hope this helps.